# Troubleshooting wiring short

Tags: wiring, receptacle

I noticed that some of the outlets in my outbuilding/shop were not working, and the breaker was tripped.  Upon resetting, it tripped again immediately.  I unplugged everything from all outlets, and it still trips. In the shop's subpanel, I disconnected the neutral wire for the circuit, and I see a short ( < 1ohm ) between the hot wire and the ground - so the short seems to be to ground, not neutral. Resistance between neutral and hot is about 1Mohm (seems low?  but probably not the cause of the short).

Any ideas on troubleshooting this?  I have no idea where the wires are physically run.  I'm guessing (hoping!) that something inside one of the outlet boxes caused the short (though, that seems odd - I've owned this building for over 20 years and no issues, I haven't touched the wiring or outlets recently, seems weird for a short to just 'spring up').  My current plan is to take apart each outlet box and look for issues, and disconnect the outlet/wiring to further isolate the problem.

Any tips or shortcuts for me? Any way to troubleshoot without opening up each box? There's maybe 6-10 outlets on this circuit.

I think all the outlet boxes in this shop are phenolic, so it seems it must be a groundwire-to-hotwire short, rather than a hot-to-box short.

Comment: With no work being done, it might be KFM(fried mice) in the walls.  It could be ground to hot in a box still, but seems low with no recent work.  Usually it is panel to closest outlet, so opening up outlet and removing the further outlets should narrow down section of wall to open.

Comment: How many circuits in the subpanel? How many outlets on the one circuit that is shorting? Are lights and receptacles on the shorting circuit?

Comment: Probably a dozen or so circuits in the panel, probably 6-10 outlets on the circuit.  Just receptacles, no lighting.

Answer (score 2):

Very much sounds like a ground wire was installed ALMOST touching a hot screw on receptacle. Or a razor knife cut in insulation touching ground wire.  Most people don't realize that electrical wiring is a DYNAMIC system. Every time a load is applied to a wire, the wire moves! This is how, after years or decades, an issue like this can present itself. Crip659's term "Kentuc_y Fried Mice" is awesome! Could even be a tiny spider just happened to be right at that "not quite a short yet," just as you hit the power on your drill press. Zzzpppt-poor spider!

Anyhow, quickest route to take is to check outlet that is most often used, then move to highest current outlet next. (Maybe where ukeep that 120v welder plugged in that's been used twice in 7 years.) If not in those 2 or 3 boxes, then start at middle box of circuit. Disconnect one set of wires from it and check for short on breaker side. If still trips go couple boxes closer to panel and repeat. This way you can save opening a lot of boxes, sometimes.